# Is there a way to conditionally declare multiple extern crates with a single configuration attribute?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

I have a few optional features that conditionally include crates. Many of them require the `#[macro_use]` attribute, so they must be defined in the entry point file, which causes a bit of redundancy with `#[cfg]` attributes. What I'd really like to do is declare multiple extern crates in their own block or in a single statement, for example:

```
#[cfg(feature = "baz-feature")]
{
    #[macro_use]
    extern crate foo_crate;

    #[macro_use]
    extern crate bar_crate;
}
```

or perhaps

```
#[cfg(feature = "baz-feature")]
extern crate {#[macro_use] foo_crate, #[macro_use] bar_crate};
```

Is there currently any way to accomplish something like the above, and if not, are there any active RFCs to do something similar?